# Перемещение ',' в окне TextField

Tags: java, javafx

Возник вопрос поставивший меня в тупик. Добавление в экземпляр `TextField` запятой в конец строки переносит запятую на начало вывода. Хотя в наблюдаемом хранилище порядок вывода верный. Ситуация в примерах `textOut.setText("123,");` в поле выведет ,123 Но если окончание прикрыть любым символом кроме запятой результат корректный. `textOut.setText("123,9");` -> 123,9

**UPD:**

Дополню примером:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    TextField field = new TextField();

    field.setFocusTraversable(false);
    field.setNodeOrientation(NodeOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
    field.setPrefWidth(300);

    Button button = new Button("magic");

    button.setOnAction(e -> {
        field.setText(field.getText().equals("123,") ? "123,0" : "123,");
    });

    VBox p = new VBox(field, button);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(p, 300, 300));
    primaryStage.show();

    field.setFont(new Font(24.0d));
    field.setText("111");

}
```

Как видно из примера ориентация поля `RIGHT_TO_LEFT` что в общем то и является первопричиной не ожидаемого поведения.

Comment: можно более подробно описать случай воспроизведения? у меня не воспроизводится

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение вашей проблемы проста, замените
`field.setNodeOrientation(NodeOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);`

на
 
`field.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_RIGHT);`

Вам же не надо весь node ориентировать а только лишь выравнивать текст

Comment: к утру уже все прояснилось)